# C ∆ (A ∩ B) ⊆ A ∪ B what is the logical statement

Tags: proof-writing

Set C is symmetric difference of set A’s intersection of set B. therefore, is a subset of set A. the result is unioned with set B.

Comment: The symmetric difference of $C$ with intersection of $A$ and $B$, is a subset of $A$ and $B$'s union.

Comment: I need the equation of this.

Comment: This statement is false for $A=B=\{1\}$, $C=\{1,2\}$, the LHS becomes $\{2\}$; the RHS becomes $\{1\}$.

Comment: "What is the logical statement" is a very unclear question. Clarify? statement about what? $C \Delta (A \cap B) \subseteq A \cup B$ is already a statement.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x.(x\in A \land x\in B \land x\notin C \lor (x\notin A\lor x\notin B)\land x \in C)\implies x\in A\lor x\in B$

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: To translate in English, "for all $x$, if $x$ is in either ($A$ and $B$'s intersection) or $C$ exclusively, then $x$ is in ($A$ and $B$'s union)". This is what the original statement means.

Comment: You are a blessing I have been struggling for 2 weeks and couldn't get no help.

Comment: You are welcome. One way to get quick help is to ask your professor directly.

Comment: I did, I didn't understand what she said, I also asked 5 math teachers with no success.

Comment: That's really sad. I think you should communicate more to understand what your professor says. After all she is the one that gives all the exams and homeworks.